# How to read the math equation in .doc file using Cocoa Obj C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring

I have a .doc file with math equation. I read the .doc file using `NSDocFormatTextDocumentType` to get the data in `NSAttributedString`. The text is OK but the Math equation can not read.

I tried to use `NSAttachmentAttributeName` but the value is always nil. How can read the equation in doc file? Thanks.

This is my some code:

```
    NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributeKey documentType = NSDocFormatTextDocumentType; // for ony .doc

    NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: documentType};
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:attrs documentAttributes:nil error:&error];

    if (attrString == nil) {
        NSLog(@"err: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"attrString: %@", attrString);
    [[self.textview textStorage] setAttributedString: attrString];
    [attrString enumerateAttribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName
                         inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length])
                         options:0
                      usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop)
     {
         if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSTextAttachment class]])
         {
             NSTextAttachment *attachment = (NSTextAttachment *)value;

         }
     }];
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with .doc (there is no equivalent in iOS), but instead of enumerating for `NSAttachmentAttributeName` only, could you enumerate for all of them? Could you also try to pinpoint the location of the maths equations (range)? Also, the maths questions from .doc may not be interpreted by `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: @Larme: yes, i tried to print it on the log but there is no equation. Is there any way to read all data the .Doc file on macOS ?

Comment: I don't know, I know that NSAttributedString don't interpret all the HTML tags for instance, so that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that you can't. The support for Word document files (.doc, .docx) in the standard libraries is limited. It is prone to formatting issues, and I strongly recommend you do not rely on it for importing detailed math equations. Your best bet is to ensure equations are submitted to your app in a more easily parseable format — mathjax, even Latex will likely have good third party libraries. I doubt there is a third party Cocoa library that can read Word math equations.

Comment: I'm saying that such a library does not exist.